# Topic Challenge: New Users

Tags: discussion, challenge

It's time for another **Community Building Challenge**!

Our [winner](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/moderators-topic-challenge/187#187) this time is [new-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-users). The idea behind this challenge is to expand the type of questions this tag covers. As it currently stands, the majority of the questions regarding these users are about how to encourage them to conform to community policies. We can expand this to include questions about how to engage these users, encourage them to stick around and contribute and not bashing them over the head with walls of rules. Of course, [new-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-users) can use questions regarding any topic that you see fit. New members are important for community growth and often a source of many questions for community members and administration.

If you have a question that is part of this challenge, please tag the question with [new-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-users). At the time of this posting, there are 11 questions in this tag. Let's build our library of questions about new users and various aspects of community building regarding this particular subset of users.

Once again, this will be a two week challenge. Our [non-digital communities challenge](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/topic-challenge-non-digital-communities) did well with this time frame. I think we'll stick with it for this challenge too. I will tally up the results on December 15th to see how we did. We are looking for high quality questions (and answers). This will take us to the start of [Winter Bash 2014](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/does-moderators-se-want-to-participate-in-winter-bash-2014).

If you have ideas for more challenge topics, post them [here](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/moderators-topic-challenge).

Let the challenge begin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our second challenge has been completed! We received two questions for this challenge - one from a user and one from a community leader:

- [Hi! I'm new and I want to participate…how do I do so?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/924/hi-im-new-and-i-want-to-participate-how-do-i-do-so)
- [How do you handle sudden growth and expansion in a mature community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/926/how-do-you-handle-sudden-growth-and-expansion-in-a-mature-community)

These questions attracted 3 different answers.

---

Thanks to the participants of this event.

[image: profile for AJ Henderson at Community Building Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for jflory7 at Community Building Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Monica Cellio at Community Building Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for user769 at Community Building Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

---

We'll take a short break on the challenges while the [Stack Exchange Winter Bash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is going on for the next couple weeks. In the meantime, take a look at our [suggestions](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/community-building-topic-challenge-ideas-thread) for future events. Feel free to vote for the items you want to be a challenge, or add your own ideas.